# Multiple assignment in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

I have a 4x4 array of zeros.

```
julia> X = zeros(4,4)
4x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

I have an 2xN array containing indices of elements in `X` that I want to assign a new value.

```
julia> ind = [1 1; 2 2; 3 3]
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
```

What is the simplest way to assign a value to all elements in `X` whose indices are rows in `ind`? (something like `X[ind] = 2.0`).

```
julia> X
 2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: You should consider changing `ind` to column-major (a 2xN-`Array`) when it is large, so looping can happen in memory order. See [this](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a non-looping way to do this. What's wrong with this?

```
for i=[1:size(ind)[1]] 
    a, b = ind[i, :]  
    X[a, b] = 2.0
end
```

Comment: I didn't know if a non-looping method exists. Actually that was my question.

Comment: There is no non-looping way to do this that is more efficient than the for loop, and I doubt there is a non-looping way that is more readable.

Comment: Well, there is this: `mapslices(x -> X[x...] = 2.0, ind, [2])`... but that is very inefficient, of course. ;)

Comment: The notation `[a:b]` is deprecated as of Julia 0.4.

Answer (score 3):

user3467349's answer is correct, but inefficient, because it allocates an `Array` for the indices. Also, the notation `[a:b]` [is deprecated](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10290) as of Julia 0.4. Instead, you can use:

```
for i = 1:size(ind, 1)
  a, b = ind[i, :]
  X[a, b] = 2.0
end
```